# Possible symmetry groups of power terms

Tags: gr.group-theory, lo.logic, finite-groups, universal-algebra

*Previously [asked and bountied at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4338046/what-are-the-symmetry-groups-of-exponentiation-only-terms):*

---

Let $\mathfrak{E}=(\mathbb{N};\mathit{exp})$ be the algebra in the sense of universal algebra consisting of the natural numbers with just exponentiation. To each term $t(x_1,...,x_n)$ in which each variable $x_i$ ($1\le i\le n$) actually appears$^1$ we can assign the group $$E_t=\{\sigma\in S_n:\forall a_1,...,a_n\in\mathbb{N}[t(a_1,...,a_n)=t(a_{\sigma(1)},...,a_{\sigma(n)})]\}.$$ For example, allowing standard notational conveniences we have $E_{x^y}$ is trivial but $E_{(x^y)^z}\cong S_2$.

I'm curious which groups arise, up to isomorphism, as $E_t$s *(in the language of [this earlier question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412563/what-term-symmetry-groups-can-an-algebra-admit), I'm asking for a description of $\mathbb{G}(\mathfrak{E})$)*. The above trick is the only useful thing I can think of, and [in a sense](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2080920/28111) is in fact all there is, but it already gives rise to some complexity: for example, at a glance the term $$[[((a^b)^c)^d]^{[((p^q)^r)^s]}]^{[((w^x)^y)^z]}$$ yields a semidirect product of $(S_3)^3$ and $S_2$, but we can then "carve out" some of that group by reusing the same variable multiple times. Intuitively I suspect that each $E_t$ can be built up from full permutation groups via semidirect products + [something else rather simple], but it seems potentially messy. There are many specific groups which seem (to me) to be plausible counterexample candidates, including the $A_n$s and $C_n$s for "large enough" values of $n$, but I haven't had any luck figuring out the situation with even such fairly <s>simple</s> low-complexity groups.

---

$^1$The answer to this specific question would not change if we allowed terms in which some variables don't appear; however, for general structures $\mathfrak{A}$ this restriction can be impactful *(e.g. if we take $\mathfrak{A}$ to be an algebra consisting of a single bijection from the square of the underlying set to itself)*, so I've included it here for consistency.

Comment: What can prevent every finite group appear as $E_t$ for some algebra and some term $t$? In fact what can prevent existence of an algebra $A$ such that every finite group occurs as $E_t$ for some term $t$ and the algebra $A$? I would not be surprised if the signature of this $A$ may be finite (two operations at most).

Comment: @markvs I'm asking in this question about the **specific case** of the algebra $(\mathbb{N};\mathit{exp})$. (In [another question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412563/what-term-symmetry-groups-can-an-algebra-admit), which I've just now retitled for clarity, I do ask about arbitrary algebras - but there I'm asking which *classes of* groups are achievable: for example, is there an algebra which gets us exactly the $2$-groups this way?)

Comment: OK, and which groups are known to be missing in this case? How about $S_n$, $n>3$?

Comment: @markvs Certainly you can get the $S_n$s by using the trick in the question: consider $x^{y_1...y_n}$ (abbreviated for simplicity).

Comment: Then what cannot occur? $A_5$?

Comment: @markvs No idea - at the moment I do not know of an example of a group which can't occur. At a guess, I'd probably start looking at the $A_n$s for decent candidates.

Comment: For the free semigroup all $E_t$ are trivial?

Comment: @markvs Yes, that's right. (BTW I tried to click "move to chat" but it failed.)

Comment: Actually, cyclic groups might be good candidates as well. (I'm sorry I don't really have anything more useful to say here - I don't actually know much group theory!)

Comment: Trivial groups are 2-groups. I do not use chat. Take a permutation $\sigma$ and the free semigroup in the variety given by the identity $x_1...x_n=x_{\sigma 1}...x_{\sigma n}$.

Comment: @markvs Sorry, I don't see how that gets an algebra whose $E_t$s are exactly the finite $2$-groups; could you say more?

Comment: It gives you an algebra where all $E_t$ are 2-groups. If you want to realize all 2-groups at once, it is a much more serious problem.

Comment: @markvs Yes, I [already know](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4337962/28111) how to get all $E_t$s to be $2$-groups; I'm trying to get *exactly* the class of finite $2$-groups. (In case it helps - although I don't think it will - I'm not wedded to $p=2$.)

Comment: If you take the variety of semigroups given by $xyzt=xzyt$ then what are the $G_t$ for the free semigroups in that variety?

Comment: @markvs No idea, sorry.

Comment: @markvs Turns out I was overthinking this one, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [an observation by MSE user Pilcrow](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4358618/do-cyclic-groups-appear-as-symmetry-groups-of-exponentiation-only-terms#comment9100944_4358618), it seems I've been overcomplicating this:

For simplicity, let "$[x_1,x_2,...,x_k]$" be shorthand for the right-associating exponent term $$x_1^{(x_2^{(...^{x_k})})}.$$ Then for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and each subgroup $G$ of $S_k$, we can consider the term $$t_G:=w^{\prod_{\sigma\in G}[x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)}...,x_{\sigma(k)}]}$$ (allowing the obvious abuse of notation for brevity), with $w,x_1,x_2,...,x_k$ distinct variables.

Since $w$ obviously can't be swapped with any of the $x_i$s there is a canonical embedding $i:E_{t_G}\rightarrow S_k$, and it's not hard (if a bit tedious) to show that in fact we have $i[E_{t_G}]=G$. So every finite group occurs as the symmetry group of some exponentiation-only term. For example, $C_4$ is represented by $w^{[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]\cdot[x_2,x_3,x_4,x_1]\cdot[x_3,x_4,x_1,x_2]\cdot[x_4,x_1,x_2,x_3]}$, or a bit less abbreviatedly by $$w^{[x_1^{(x_2^{(x_3^{x_4})})}]\cdot[x_2^{(x_3^{(x_4^{x_1})})}]\cdot[x_3^{(x_4^{(x_1^{x_2})})}]\cdot[x_4^{(x_1^{(x_2^{x_3})})}]}.$$